# \ShowHook, but only the code for a specific label

Tags: hooks, lthooks

`\ShowHook` and its L3 counterpart `\hook_show:n` provided by `lthooks` are documented to print in the terminal a number of pieces of information about a given hook, including "the code chunks (and their labels) added to it".

Is there a way to show only the code chunk(s) for a given label?

(If that matters, the use case is that I want to inspect the code a package adds to a hook in a regression test, and would really prefer not to test everything that goes into the hook, just what the package adds).

Comment: well there is naturally a way, but no user interface. But in general I would say that even in regression tests you would want everything. If the hook is important for you you also need to know if a package adds to it - e.g. to decide if a rule is needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, in my experience, this turns the test over sensitive to upstream changes, not always relevant ones. And in the case at hand, I don't really expect this particular code chunk to interact with other ones in the same hook, so it'd make sense to just test for that, I think. Anyway, "no user interface" sounds like it answers the question, if you'd like to add it as such, I'd be happy to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by @UlrikeFischer in the comments: no, there's no user interface to show only the code chunks of selected labels.